# Converting nonstationary process

Tags: stationarity, seasonality, trend

I am looking at the hourly load demand profile for an entire year. See image below. However, from my understanding of stationarity, this process is non stationary as it has seasonality as well as a non linear trend. 
[image: Hourly Load Demand]
Now I have used seasonal differencing (for both 24 hr and 24 * 7 = 168hr periodicity) in MATLAB to remove the trend and seasonality. The image below used 24 hr periodicity. But some of the values are now negative. Is this differenced signal the stationary process or do I need to use this to obtain the stationary process. I am new to this concept of converting a nonstationary process to a stationary process.  I would appreciate any advice on this matter.
[image: Differenced Hourly Load]

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be focusing on a rear-window approach i.e a SARIMA aproach to modelling your data heavily depending on differencing.

There is a causal approach that you might consider.

Your series may have hourly effects ,daily effects, monthly effects, pre and post holiday effects, pulse effects, day-of-the-month-effects, week-of-the-month effects and perhaps weather/temperature effects. It does not appear to have non-linear trend effects just a response to unspecified predictor series. There may also be short term arima effects. Only your data knows for sure !

Data like this arises regularly for call center forecasting and of course for different kinds of demqnds for human services.

Instead of memory-driven pure SARIMA (endogenous) models, we have found that tactical demand data reflects human patterns that are often based on some of the deterministic (exogenous) factors/habits that I have listed above reflecting different patterns for different kinds of days.

Take a look at https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A3382+hourly+data to get some ideas on this topic.

Answer (score 0):

From the post, it is not quite clear what is your goal, prediction or modeling or something else.

However, with respect to modeling, some statisticians modeled these kinds of data by a combination of Gaussian processes with different kernels, see here:
https://andrewgelman.com/2012/06/19/slick-time-series-decomposition-of-the-birthdays-data/
https://andrewgelman.com/2017/01/17/laurie-davies-time-series-decomposition-birthday-data/
https://andrewgelman.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/births.pdf

They also have code there.